# Calculation of RTT - Winsock

Tags: tcp, winsock

I need to dynamically choose a RWIN size for my TCP program in order to increase the throughput. Since RWIN is calculated as the product of Bandwidth and RTT I would like to know if there is any means to get the RTT using Winsock API.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but in any case you should just assume the worst and set the buffer big. Setting it biger than necessary will only cost you space, not time. The Windows default used to be 8k which was always miles too small. Set it up around 52k and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: Fine. Wont setting the receiver window to the max possible value increase re-transmissions? It wouldn't be a problem if TCP uses selective repeat by default. But how can I make sure whether its using  selective repeat or go back n by default?